# Formula for the analytical computation of Eigenvalues for random walks of order one and two on regular lattices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-walk

I have a question with respect to random walk penalties in statistics. In Bayesian statistics an adequate prior for modeling a $n$-dimensional random vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ as a random walk of order $d$ is given by 
$$
p(\boldsymbol{x}|\kappa) \propto \exp\left( -\frac{\kappa}{2}\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{K}_d\boldsymbol{x} \right)
$$ 
where the $n\times n$ matrix $\boldsymbol{K}_d$ is the structure matrix. For random walks of order one and two we have

\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{K}_{1} & =\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & -1\\
 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\
 &  & -1 & 2 & -1\\
 &  &  & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right) & \text{and} &  & \boldsymbol{K}_{2} & =\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & -2 & 1\\
-2 & 5 & -4 & 1\\
1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1\\
 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
 &  & 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 \\
 &  & & 1 & -4 & 5 & -2 \\
 &  & & & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
I'm interested in the non-zero Eigenvalues $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ of these matrices. For $d=1$ you can find the following formula in the literature:
$$
\lambda_i = 2 - 2\cos(\pi(i-1)/n), \quad i=1,\dots,n.
$$
I'm wondering (a) how this formula can be derived (the only sentence I found in the literature was "it is easily checked ...") and (b) if a similar statement can be made for $d=2$?

I'm thankful for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvectors of circulant matrices are Fourier modes. $\mathbf K_1$ isn't quite a circulant matrix, but you can arrange the phase such that the missing entries don't contribute. The eigenvalue formula then follows by

\begin{eqnarray}
&&2\sin ax-\sin a(x+1)-\sin a(x-1)\\&=&2\sin ax-\sin ax\cos a-\cos ax\sin a-\sin ax\cos a+\cos ax\sin a\\&=&\sin ax(2-2\cos a)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Unfortunately the same thing won't work for $\mathbf K_2$ because you can't make all four boundary rows come out right with one phase shift. [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigensystem%20of%20%7B%7B1%2C-2%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B-2%2C5%2C-4%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C-4%2C6%2C-4%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C-4%2C6%2C-4%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C-4%2C5%2C-2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C-2%2C1%7D%7D) returns some not very nice eigenvalues for $n=6$ (which should have nice eigenvalues if they could be expressed in terms of multiples of $\pi/6$).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I didn't draw the connection to circulant matrices, so thank you for pointing this out. For d=2 you confirmed my believe that it is not possible to derive a similar formula.